# Spacemacs - Changing evil keys (swapping)

Tags: key-bindings, evil, spacemacs

I use a different keyboard layout (colemak) so standard evil keys are a bit annoying. Is there a way to swap keys globally (minus when writing text)?

Comment: I don't have experience with using alternative layouts, but it seems like `toggle-input-method` (bound to `C-\\` ) might work for this.  It changes the keys for typing, but not for navigation.

Comment: Sorry I forget a tag, I was specifically asking about spacemacs.

Comment: Spacemacs has a [layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bintl/keyboard-layout) for different keyboard layouts. I've never used it, but maybe it's a start for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I need. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Wieland Can you write your comment as an answer? Hortenson, can you then accept it?

Comment: If forget to come back to this. Actually this method is not working completely, certain keys cannot be exchanged. I don't really have the time/knowledge to look at source of the layer to say why that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may be looking for https://github.com/wbolster/evil-colemak-basics which provides basic rebindings that aren't "a bit annoying" but instead an awesome mix of colemak and qwerty that feels very natural for seasoned vim/evil users switching to colemak.

(i am the author.)

Comment: This is really great and with minor modifications probably the setup I had before. But does this work with spacemacs? In the sense that the spacemacs keys get rewired as well?

Comment: i do not use spacemacs, so please be more specific. evil-colemak-basics is a minor mode that overrides key bindings in motion, normal and visual states (and a few extra things) which are provided by evil. afaik spacemacs uses evil so in theory this should work as-is.

Comment: Spacemacs uses leader key and vim keys to do everything in emacs. So ideally I wanted to swap the keys there as well. Anyway clearly your package doesn't do that but works well inside a buffer so thanks a lot.

Comment: A late thanks, I revisited your package and it works well now with spacemacs.

Comment: ok wow, so you actually use it? any feedback or improvements that come to mind? (use github please)